# Display Win if our score is greater than opponent's score or Loss if our score is less than theirs

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

I'm using PHP to output an XML feed of our Stanford Athletics scores, in this example men's basketball. Two of the attributes are both teams' scores, 'hs' is home score and 'vs' is visitor score (for example, Oregon State vs Stanford XML attributes are: hs="67" vs="69").
'hn' and 'vn' are the home name and the visitor name (for example, 'Stanford' or 'Oregon State').
Additional 'hc' and 'vc' are the home city and the visitor city, and contains the first 4 letters of the city name (for example, Stanford would be 'stan' and 'Oregon State' would be 'oreg'). Note: as Cat only is three letters long, so is the 'hc' and 'vc' for Cat being 'cat'.

My question is, is it possible to display "Win" if the Stanford score is greater than the opponent's score, or display "Loss" is the Stanford score is less than the opponent's score? For example, Oregon State beat Stanford, so how can I display "at Oregon State - Loss"?

Here is my [page](http://bit.ly/j8CwSq), [XML](http://bit.ly/kfowoN) and code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml');

// Reverse chronological order
$xmlArray = array();
foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;
$xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date)
{
    // Only output if complete
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    {
    // Only show opponents' name
    $name = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];
    // Output "vs" if home game or "at" if away game
    $preposition = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan') ? 'vs' : 'at';
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $preposition, ' ', $name, '</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: don't forget that some sports may have results that need to be expressed as ties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$home = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan');
echo '<h3>', $preposition, ' ', $name, ' - ', ((int)$event_date->event['hs'] == (int)$event_date->event['vs'] ? "Tie" : (((int)$event_date->event['hs'] > (int)$event_date->event['vs']) ? ($home? 'Win' : 'Loss') : ($home ? 'Loss' : 'Win'))), '</h3>';
```

Put these in your foreach loop, and i've also added a "Tie" thingy.

By defining the $home variable you could replace these lines:

```
 // Only show opponents' name
 $name = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];
// Output "vs" if home game or "at" if away game
$preposition = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan') ? 'vs' : 'at';
```

with these:

```
// Home?
$home = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan');
// Only show opponents' name
$name = $home ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];
// Output "vs" if home game or "at" if away game
$preposition = $home ? 'vs' : 'at';
```

and you wouldn't need the $home in the code i wrote.

So here is the complete code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml');

// Reverse chronological order
$xmlArray = array();
foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;
$xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date)
{
    // Only output if complete
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    {
    // Home?
    $home = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan');
    // Only show opponents' name
    $name = $home ? $event_date->event['vn'] : $event_date->event['hn'];
    // Output "vs" if home game or "at" if away game
    $preposition = $home ? 'vs' : 'at';
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $preposition, ' ', $name, ' - ', ((int)$event_date->event['hs'] == (int)$event_date->event['vs'] ? "Tie" : (((int)$event_date->event['hs'] > (int)$event_date->event['vs']) ? ($home? 'Win' : 'Loss') : ($home ? 'Loss' : 'Win'))), '</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
}   
?>
```

Expanded code with "if's" and more comments:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml');

// Reverse chronological order
$xmlArray = array();
foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;
$xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date)
{
    // Only output if complete
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    {
    // Home?
    $home = ($event_date->event['hc'] == 'stan');
    // Only show opponents' name
    $name = $home ? $event_date->event['vn'] : $event_date->event['hn'];
    // Output "vs" if home game or "at" if away game
    $preposition = $home ? 'vs' : 'at';
    if((int)$event_date->event['hs'] == (int)$event_date->event['vs']) // Tie?
    {
    $result = 'Tie'; // Tie
    }
    else if((int)$event_date->event['hs'] > (int)$event_date->event['vs']) // Home team won?
    {
    if($home) // Home?
    {
    $result = 'Win'; // You're home and the home team won
    }
    else
    {
    $result = 'Loss'; // You're away, but the home team won
    }
    }
    else // Home team lost
    {
    if($home) // Home?
    {
    $result = 'Loss'; // You're away, but the home team won
    }
    else
    {
    $result = 'Win'; // You're home and the home team won
    }
    }
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $preposition, ' ', $name, ' - ', $result, '</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need two places that echo "Win" or "Loss".

Comment: I don't, it only produces one "Win" or "Loss" (or "Tie")

Comment: @Tyilo: I mean this -- `? ($home? 'Win': 'Loss'): ($home? 'Loss': 'Win'))`

Comment: @Tylio wow thanks for all of your effort! When I run your code there are a couple problems: 1. All the h3's are changed to "Stanford" when they should be the name of the opposing team (as in my page URL); 2. The Win/Loss is being determined by the home team, when it should be based on its relation to Stanford, i.e. if Stanford has more points echo "Win", if Stanford has fewer points echo "Loss." If you can make that happen I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @jnpcl It does the matching between if you're away or home and if the home team is winning or loosing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$event_date->event['hs']` is the **Home Score** and `$event_date->event['vs']` is the **Versus Score**:

```
echo ($event_date->event['hs'] > $event_date->event['vs']) ? 'WIN' : 'LOSS';
```

Or, if there's the potential of a tie game:

```
echo ($event_date->event['hs'] > $event_date->event['vs']) ? 'WIN' : ($event_date->event['hs'] < $event_date->event['vs']) ? 'LOSS' : 'TIE';
```

**Note:** The output of this answer is all based on the Home Team. Since you need it to always be in reference to Stanford, @Tyilo's answer is a better match.

Comment: I think you meant to say that 'vs' is the **Versus Score** in your opening sentence.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks. Another copy-paste mishap. :o

Comment: @jnpcl thanks for your reply. When I try your code it displays "LOSS" for all the results. If the Stanford score is greater than the opponent's, it should output "Win", if Stanford scored less it should be "Loss." Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Ryan: What are the values for `$event_date->event['hs']` and `$event_date->event['vs']`?

Comment: @jnpcl 'hs' is home score and 'vs' is visitor score. I edited my question to clarify that. So Stanford could be home or visitor, the important thing is whether or not they had more points than the opponent (who could also be home or visitor).

Comment: @Ryan: I noted in my answer that 'WIN' and 'LOSS' will always be in reference to the Home Team, which may or may not be Stanford. See @Tyilo's answer for a better solution.

Comment: @jnpcl unfortunately I can't seem to get Tylio's answer to work (posted a comment to it). If you have any ideas on how to get this working I'd really appreciate it :)